# Is $\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{\theta}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{\theta}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{\theta}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{\theta}$$

or

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{\theta}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}\theta}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{\theta^n}$$ ???

Comment: The second one is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter, which can be seen by writing it out;
$$\prod_{i=1}^n{\frac{x_i}{\theta}}=\frac{x_1}{\theta}\cdot\frac{x_2}{\theta}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{x_n}{\theta}=\frac{x_1\cdot x_2\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n}{\theta\cdot\theta\cdot\ldots\cdot\theta}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}}{\theta^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

A small complement on @Eric's answer:
More generally, for every $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\Bbb C$ and every $y_1,\ldots,y_n\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{y_i}=\frac{x_1}{y_1}\cdot \frac{x_2}{y_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot \frac{x_n}{y_n}=\frac{x_1\cdot x_2\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n}{y_1\cdot y_2\cdot\ldots\cdot y_n}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^nx_i}{\prod_{i=1}^ny_i}.$$
And in particular, if $y_1=\ldots=y_n=\theta$, then $\prod_{i=1}^ny_i=\theta^n$.